# TypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S64') dtype('S64') dtype('S64')

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate periodogram using my code

```
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('27000.dat')]
x = np.array(x)
fs=64

f, Pxx_den = signal.periodogram(x, fs)
plt.semilogy(f, Pxx_den)
plt.xlabel('frequency [Hz]')
plt.ylabel('PSD [V**2/Hz]')
plt.show()
```

But I got

```
  File "m3.py", line 9, in <module>
    f, Pxx_den = signal.periodogram(x, fs)
  File "/home/milenko/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/signal/spectral.py", line 141, in periodogram
    scaling, axis)
  File "/home/milenko/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/signal/spectral.py", line 273, in welch
    return_onesided, scaling, axis)
  File "/home/milenko/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/signal/spectral.py", line 391, in csd
    mode='psd')
  File "/home/milenko/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/signal/spectral.py", line 824, in _spectral_helper
    scale = 1.0 / (fs * (win*win).sum())
TypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S64') dtype('S64') dtype('S64')
```

Why?
I am on Ubuntu 16.04,Python 2.7.11.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35013726/typeerror-ufunc-add-did-not-contain-a-loop-with-signature-matching-types)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35013726/typeerror-ufunc-add-did-not-contain-a-loop-with-signature-matching-types), the obscure error code comes from running numpy functions on string data rather than floating-point data. The call to `rstrip` [returns a string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rstrip). I don't know what your data file looks like, but adding `x = x.astype(np.float)` after `x = np.array(x)` should fix your problem.